# How do I check if a Python script is running in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a Python script is running in PHP, but I've no idea how.
I've tried using a database: I added an entry "request" with value response "0" and the Python script had to change that value to "1" if it was online. I couldn't get that to work so now I'm asking here

Comment: Which OS is in use?

Comment: I'm using Windows

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `tasklist` is available, this could potentially work: (this example using Windows 10)

I first launched a `test2.py` script:

[image]

The `test2.py` code is simply running:

```
from time import sleep

while True:
    print('running');
    sleep(3);
```

Then using this bit of php code: (I named `procCheck.php`)

```
<?php
$tasks = [];

// Use -v to include the window title info:
exec('tasklist -v 2>NUL', $tasks);

// Check the tasks array for the script we seek:
$entry = preg_grep('/(test2\.py)/', $tasks);

if (!empty($entry)) {
    foreach($entry as $value) {
        echo $value . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Gives this output: (one wrapped line in my console window)

[image]

Know that if there are other windows open with same script name within the window title will be found too. For example, I had the `test2.py` open as the active tab in Notepad++ and that entry was found as well:

[image]

Changing to some other file tab in Notepad++ only found the first entry.